# How do I install bully and mdk3 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux-tools

How do I find and install the [Bully](http://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/bully) and [Mdk3](http://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/mdk3) tools from Kali Linux on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 11):

Bully can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 21.10 and later by running these commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install bully
```

Bully can be installed in Ubuntu 21.04 and earlier by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt -y install libpcap-dev libssl-dev aircrack-ng unzip
wget https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-security-team/bully/-/archive/debian/master/bully-debian-master.zip
unzip bully-debian-master.zip
cd bully-*/
cd src
make # makes a file named bully
sudo make install
```

mdk3 can be installed in Ubuntu 17.10 and later from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install mdk3
```

In Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb can be downloaded from [Ubuntu — Package Download Selection — mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/mdk3/download). Open a terminal, use `cd` to change directories to the directory where mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb is located and install it using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Who is `aanarchyy`? Has anyone audited that "bully" code? Who knows what's in it. Why is the repo linked from https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/bully dead? How about https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/bully/ instead?

Comment: @DanDascalescu The owner of the bully repo linked from https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/bully has deleted his GitHub and GitlLab accounts, which raises the question if that person is still a package maintainer of that project.

Comment: You should probably clone and build the official source that Kali is using: https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-security-team/bully

Comment: @jiroch Thanks for posting a very helpful comment. In fact this entire answer needed to be updated. bully is currently a package in the official Debian bullseye repositories, and it's also in the default repositories of Ubuntu 21.10 and later.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to install them with apt, katoolin will also will not work. That's what happened to me.
You need add kali repository and then install it. It worked for me.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
sudo echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo echo "deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bully mdk3
```