# How to Install bully - airgeddon tool

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, network-monitoring, testing

I did install airgeddon and other tools however I'm stock in installing bully I did try:

```
sudo apt-get install bully
```

but the result is

> Unable to locate package bully

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, I see it available only for some releases, so are you trying to install it on supported release?  (I don't know your release as you didn't state)

Comment: Please read and then edit your question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install bully and mdk3 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867071/how-do-i-install-bully-and-mdk3-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus)